# How to combine Excel data from 40 Workbooks with 25 Worksheets in each?

Tags: sql, vba, excel, odbc

I have 40 Excel Workbooks each with 25 Worksheets containing data in columns A:Q and variable number of rows (would be less than 5000 rows).

Each of the 40 Workbooks represents 1 Team. Each of the 25 Worksheets is 1 month's worth of data and the sheets are named 'Jan-15', 'Feb-15' etc... to 'Dec-16', so obviously only 5 sheets have data within them so far (as it is now May-15). Each workbook is set up for future data.

I need to get all the data into one place, which I thought would be best to use a pivot table. So far, I have set up an additional workbook that contains VBA code to pull the required data into one Pivot table. It does this by having checkboxes on a Sheet for each team and more checkboxes for each month. If the checkbox is checked (= TRUE), then the data for that team and month will be pulled through.

E.g. If 'Team 1' and 'Jan-15' is selected, the pivot table will show Team 1's January data. If 'Team 5' and 'Mar-15' is selected, then Team 1 and Team 5's Jan and March data will be pulled through.

Is does this in VBA by compiling an SQL string of the required data (my SQL knowledge is limited to 2 days' research!), such as:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `Team 13.xlsx`.[JAN-15$] 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
  FROM `Team 13.xlsx`.[FEB-15$] 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
  FROM `Team 13.xlsx`.[MAR-15$] 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
  FROM `Team 15.xlsx`.[JAN-15$] 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
  FROM `Team 15.xlsx`.[FEB-15$] 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
  FROM `Team 15.xlsx`.[MAR-15$]"  
   etc....
```

Sometimes I will only need to see, say Team 3's data for Jan-15 and Feb-15, sometimes I'll need Teams 1 to 10's data for Mar-15 and sometimes I'll need to see all 40 Teams' data over the last 12 months.

However, I am struggling now, because this only works for a certain number of selections. I only need to select up to 12 months at a time, so I have limited the number of 'month' checkboxes that can be selected, but I can't select all 40 of the Teams and all 12 months as I get an error message that says

> Run-time error '1004': [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Query is too complex.

If I only select 10 Teams and 5 Months, or 40 Teams and 1 Month, the Query runs fine, but I need more.

Is my SQL code wrong, or is there a better way to write it?

Or is there another way that I can combine all this data? (I only have Excel, not Access, at my disposal!)

Comment: There is a limit to the number of unions you can perform in a SQL Query using this method.  Is there a reason why you can't use VBA to simply copy the values?

Comment: You could just pull the data from each file, one at a time and paste it into the "Master" spreadsheet (for all the files that are requested with the checkboxes). Then each time before you paste, check the last row with data in the sheet. This way, the query won't get too complex and you'll get all of the required data in the Master sheet.  (This is the same idea as Mr. Mascaro, but I hadn't refreshed the page and seen his suggestion).

Answer (score 2):

Your query is good, you have, just as the error says, simply created too complex a query for the poor [Jet* Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine) to handle. I would suggest that you break it down into a simple loop where you handle each team/month check box combo as a separate query, each one pulling data into your master sheet and *appending* it to then end of your data set that the pivot table is built off of.

With some testing, you may determine that you can pull a team for a year without overwhelming the database engine, and write your code to work that way (up to 12 `Union`'s, for example), but that would make your code more complex. You may find that it will execute a bit faster by not having to make so many SQL queries, but then again, because they are more complex, they may execute more slowly.

*Yes, I know it's not called "Jet" any more, but I choose to let the Wiki link handle the fine lines, and most people probably still call it that despite what Microsoft wants us to do.

Comment: Sorry, my rep isn't high enough to vote up your answer FreeMan :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to the people that responded to this question. Your help and experience is greatly appreciated :-)

I have managed to sort this out today using the comments posted; using VBA to loop through workbooks and worksheets using the checked boxes to copy the data from each sheet into a master sheet within another (report) workbook and then to use VBA to create a pivot table from the master data.

Thank you to **FreeMan** for posting an answer, however unfortunately my SQL and Query skills are very limited and I didn't understand or know how to implement your suggestion! So I thought my VBA solution would be the easiest for me to do and it works.

I think initially I was over-complicating the issue with trying to use Query/SQL, but I found that that was the way to go based on the research I did trawling the 'net beforehand. I thought that copying all the data across may be too time consuming and difficult, but it turns out it was not.

I can post the code I used to check the checkboxes, open a file, select worksheets, copy data across and create a pivot table if anyone needs to do the same.

Hopefully this can help someone out in the future!

NGH